# Plural form of series when talking about literature?

Tags: grammar, irregular-plurals

When speaking about non-mathematical groups of items (i.e. a series), is there a plural usage for the word series?

> My favorite book series are all crime novels.

Is it correct to use series as a plural here?

Comment: Series is a singular in this case. My favorite book series is ....

Comment: When you are talking about one book series, that is correct. But what about one, or two, or more?

Comment: Please restate your question in a clearer fashion and I'll give you an answer.

Comment: When you are saying 'my favorite book series _are_...', 'series' does not sound right. So I was wondering if the word 'series' as both a singular and plural noun still holds in this context where you aren't just talking about one book series.

Comment: Did you mean to duplicate 'are'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *series* is one of those irregular nouns in English which is the same both singular and plural.

Moose and deer have the same issue.

> Four moose ate my mother's chocolate mousse cake.  (It was very ironic.)  All four moose are now diabetic.
>
> A moose walked into a bar and the bartender said, "Why the long face?". The moose said, "That's a joke about a horse."  A moose is not to be joked with.
>
> My favorite series is *Ethel the Aardvark's Adventures in Quantity Surveying.*
>
> My favorite series are always written by people who sniff glue.

Comment: But wait. That can be found in any good dictionary.

Comment: @Kris plenty of bad ones, too.  To be fair, I looked at the dictionary entries for series first and I didn't see any that addressed it's usage as a plural. So, I chose to answer.

Comment: No. An asker is **expected** to consult a (necessarily good) dictionary **before** posting a Q here.

Comment: @Kris as I said, the research I did before answering left the usage up in the air. No examples of it as a plural. It's a weak question but slid by for that.

Comment: I said the **asker** (OP), not the answerer.

Comment: @Kris yes, then you commented on my answer. I explained why I chose to answer despite the weakness of the question.